# linear-gradient not working in ionic3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, sass, ionic3, linear-gradients

I am trying to create a new gradient color in my Ionic3 variable.sass file.

```
$colors: (
  primary:    #4471C1,
  secondary:  #32db64,
  danger:     #f53d3d,
  light:      #f4f4f4,
  dark:       #222,
  newcolor: linear-gradient(#0fe2f3, #4caefe)
);
```

This is giving me the following error

```
The value`` must be a color.
```

How can I add a gradient color?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try as shown below.

*app.scss*

```
.toolbar-background {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-55deg, #50a2a7 35%, #e9b44c 100%) !important;
}
```

*UI*

When I applied it to my app:

[image]

Comment: So I write the above code in my variable.sass file. Please let me know how do I use `background-gradient`. If I assign it like `$toolbar-background: background-gradient;` it doesn't work

Comment: You need to put that in `app.scss` file.

Comment: Understood. Now if I want to use `background-gradient` for my `$toolbar-background` variable to change all toolbars in a go, how and where do I do it. Sorry, new with designing part.

Comment: That's brilliant... Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped :)